# Как скрыть часть элемента за блоком?

Tags: html, css, position

Как скрыть часть элемента как на фото. Чтобы верхняя часть была сзади и нижняя часть спереди. Как будто схлопнулись два элемента. Два элемента с именем и профессии я уже сделал.

```
<div class="faq__hero-icon">
  <img src="./images/icons/woman.png" alt="woman">
  // Тут оранжевый круг.
</div>
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужен overflow: hidden;
Есть твой случай https://qna.habr.com/q/656488

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/876224)

Comment: @wchistow понял, спасибо, учту)

Comment: А ещё `overflow: hidden` скроет всё, что вылезает за пределы блока, а тут нужен другой подход.

Comment: Тут бы вообще в идеале сделать эту картинку с кружком вместе, чтобы не запариваться с обрезанием через css